# Why does the Constituent Summary & Detail reports contain deleted contacts? (or, how to remove them?)

Tags: drupal, civireport, 4.7, reports

The constituent summary & constituent detail reports both contain deleted contacts - this is 4.7.21 (and 4.7.23) under Drupal.  I verified the problem on [this](https://demo.circle-interactive.co.uk/) demo site.  This doesn't seem right to me - is this a bug or WAD? Either way, any advice on how to remove them from these reports? If a bug I will report it, of course, but I wonder whether I'm missing something obvious here!

Comment: This is reported but not fixed: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20545

Comment: Thanks Jon - you should put this in as the answer?  cos it is!  Andy

Comment: Appreciated!  I didn't bother because it doesn't actually solve your problem :)  I did put in a word to raise the priority of the bug, which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the answer is that the contacts probably haven't been deleted but are in Trash.  You can search for deleted contacts in Advanced Search>Search Settings where you'll see a box labeled "Search in Trash".  On completion of the search, click on Actions and they can be deleted permanently there.  They will probably not then appear in your reports.

Comment: This is true - but "soft deleted" contacts didn't appear in reports before 4.7.15.  This is a new bug since 4.7.15-ish

Comment: I'm aware of that but the client doesn't want to permanently delete them.  Anyway, these reports shouldn't show deleted contacts - it's a bug as Jon says